# Comparing two times using strtotime and time in PHP

Tags: php

I have a start time of 3:30 pm and end time of 4:14:59 pm. Both the values are strings so I used strtotime() to convert them. I'm not sure it is taking into account the am while testing. I want to get the current time and check to see if the current time is between those two values.

```
$server_time = strtotime("3:55 AM");    

if($server_time > strtotime($start) && $server_time < strtotime($end))
{
    echo "TRUE";            
}
else
{
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

This should be false considering my server time is AM and my start and end are both PM. This is returning true though. Is there a better way to handle this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show how `$start` and `$end` are defined.

Comment: As an exercise/demo: http://codepad.org/iOjzeZR2

Comment: I'm pulling the start and end values from the db. Let me check to see if there is an issue with those. Thanks for the sample.

Comment: What was the answer/solution?

Comment: I thought I declared the column in the db as varchar and I declared it as timespan, so there was no am or pm attached to my start and end time. Like usual, the code was working like it should, the user was not. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, either add an answer below or delete this question. I suggest the former, since it could help someone else. You can mark it as the answer after a period of time (I don't know how long, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strtotime is extremely picky, i tend to use it only for mysql date conversion to timestamp. There should be no problem analyzing dates with AM and PM, but for the sake of simplicity, use military times if you don't want to have troubles converting your dates.

For example:

```
Military: 16:34:59
Standard: 4:34:59 PM
```

Comment: It's not *picky*, it just needs to follow the *[Supported date and time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)*.